# OrientDB fetchplan

Tags: java, memory, orientdb

I have a problem with the `fetchplan` in OrientDB 2.2.35

My situation is the following: I have a graph with 2 vertex classes: `ridClass` and `tokenClass` and they are connected over lightweight edges like this:
`ridClass->tokenClass->ridClass`
In my program I want to start from a vertex of the `ridClass` and want to traverse to all connected vertices of the `tokenClass` and from these to all connected vertices of the `ridClass`. I use SQL to find a start-vertex (`ridClass`) and the `GremlinPipeline` to traverse the graph.

I start a new thread for each cpu core, so in my case I start 4 threads. In each thread it looks like this:

```
GremlinPipeline pipe = new GremlinPipeline();
OrientDynaElementIterable orientDynaElementIterable = graph.command(new OCommandSQL("select from #18:" + String.valueOf(indexPosition) + " fetchplan ridClass:3")).execute();
pipe.start(orientDynaElementIterable);
pipe.out();
List<Vertex> currentTokenList = pipe.toList();
for (Vertex currentToken : currentTokenList) {
    GremlinPipeline pipe2 = new GremlinPipeline();
    pipe2.start(currentToken);
    pipe2.out();
    List<Vertex> currentRIDList = pipe2.toList();
    for (Vertex currentRidVertex : currentRIDList) {
        //here I do something with the vertices...
    }
}
```

From the logic I get the right vertices, but the problem is the `fetchplan`. If I use the `fetchplan ridClass:3` like in the `graph.command` in my code above, my program is not faster, rather a little bit slower than if I don't set a `fetchplan`. I thought with this `fetchplan` it returns with the SQL query additional all connected vertices of the `tokenClass` and from these the next  `ridClass` vertices into the cache? Is it probably to much for the cache or I understand the fetchplan wrong? Even if I reduce the depth level of the `fetchplan` like this `fetchplan ridClass:1`, my program is slower.

My OrientDB configuration looks like this (my computer has 8gb RAM):

```
<properties>
    <entry value="1" name="db.pool.min"/>
    <entry value="50" name="db.pool.max"/>
    <entry value="false" name="profiler.enabled"/>
    <entry value="6000" name="storage.diskCache.bufferSize"/>
    <entry value="false" name="storage.useWAL"/>
    <entry value="4000" name="hashTable.slitBucketsBuffer.length"/>
    <entry value="8" name="storage.diskCache.writeCachePart"/>
    <entry value="500" name="storage.record.lockTimeout"/>
    <entry value="notx_sync_repair" name="sql.graphConsistencyMode"/>
</properties>
```

Maybe someone has an idea for this problem.

Kind regards

Comment: Hi, are you using indexes? Thx

Comment: No, I use the default @rid